# Why I am getting wrong fs type bad option error for ntfs drives?

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs

Last night I gracefully shut down my computer and currently now I getting a weird error like in the attached image.
I tried all the possible option but nothing seems to work. This happens for the very first time with me.
[image]

Comment: If you're dual-booting with any Windows 8 or newer then disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must. If that isn't the cause then you need to repair the file system from Windows.

Comment: Thank you. Disabling Fast Startup worked perfectly. You can post it as answer and I will accept it. :)